# How to change color-scheme dynamically in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, styling, color-scheme

[image]

in my react app I want to dynamically change the color scheme like the image above but it's not working at all (it doesn't change scroll bar color), knowing that any other attribute like "background-color" is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enable CSS baseline style:

```
...
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";

...
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  {/* A collection of HTML element and attribute style-normalizations. */}
  <CssBaseline enableColorScheme />
  ...
</ThemeProvider>
...
```